# Как сортировать NSMutableArray со своими объектами?

Tags: массивы, objective-c, сортировка

У меня есть `NSMutableArray` с своими объектами `Person`, я хочу отсортировать этот массив по *Person.birthDate* типа `NSDate`. Вероятно, должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(???)];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Compare method

Создайте также сравнивающий метод для Вашего объекта:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Person *)otherObject {
    return [self.birthDate compare:otherObject.birthDate];
}

NSArray *sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

### NSSortDescriptor (предпочтительный способ)

Зачастую более предпочтительный вариант — использовать дескрипторы:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"birthDate"
                                              ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Вы можете сортировать по множеству ключей просто добавив дополнительные дескрипторы в массив. Также возможно использование своих сравнивающих методов. Взгляните на [документацию](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

### Blocks (блестящий способ)

На Mac OS X 10.6 and iOS 4 и выше можно сортировать с использованием блоков:

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDate *first = [(Person*)a birthDate];
    NSDate *second = [(Person*)b birthDate];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

## Производительность

Использование `-compare:` и блоков работает в целом несколько быстрее, чем описание массива дескрипторов, так как они используют [*Key-Value-Coding*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html). Основное преимущество `NSSortDescriptor` в том, что он позволяет определять порядок сортировки описывая больше данные, чем код. Благодаря этому можно довольно легко предоставить пользователю возможность выбирать порядок сортировки, например, кликая по заголовкам столбиков в `NSTableView`.

<sub>Перевод ответа: [How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805589/5308802)</sub>